# SQL Server Backup and Shrink Script Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm having an issue getting my backup/shrink script working properly.

I keep getting an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near 'CONCAT'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near 'CONCAT'.`

Error every time I attempt to run it.

Can you help?

```
Declare @dbname VarChar(250);
Declare @logfile VarChar(1000);
Declare @baklocation VarChar(1000) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\BACKUP\';

Select @dbname = name From sys.databases Where name Not In ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');
While @@rowcount <> 0
Begin
    Alter DATABASE [@dbname] Set RECOVERY SIMPLE With NO_WAIT;

    Backup Database @dbname 
        TO DISK = CONCAT(@baklocation, @dbname, '\', @dbname, '_', Convert(Varchar(500),GetDate(),112), '.bak');

    Backup Log @dbname 
        TO DISK = CONCAT(@baklocation, @dbname, '\', @dbname, '_', Convert(Varchar(500),GetDate(),112), '.log.bak');

End;

SELECT @logfile = filename FROM SYSALTFILES Where groupid = 0 AND dbid > 4;
While @@rowcount <> 0
Begin
    DBCC SHRINKFILE(@logfile, 1);
End;
```

Comment: `CONCAT` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** - it's **not** available in earlier versions, so if this runs against SQL Server 2008, obviously you'll get errors....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try this:

**CONCAT is available in 2012 or Greater**

So create Variable and Assign those values to IT

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

```
Declare @dbname VarChar(250);
Declare @logfile VarChar(1000);
Declare @baklocation VarChar(1000) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\BACKUP\';
Declare @Newvar nvarchar(MAx)

Select @dbname = name From sys.databases Where name Not In ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');
While @@rowcount <> 0
Begin
    Alter DATABASE [@dbname] Set RECOVERY SIMPLE With NO_WAIT;
set @Newvar= @baklocation + @dbname + '\' + @dbname + '_' + Convert(Varchar(500),GetDate(),112)+ '.bak'
    Backup Database @dbname 
        TO DISK =@Newvar ;

    Backup Log @dbname 
        TO DISK = @Newvar;

End;

SELECT @logfile = filename FROM SYSALTFILES Where groupid = 0 AND dbid > 4;
While @@rowcount <> 0
Begin
    DBCC SHRINKFILE(@logfile, 1);
End;
```

Comment: Ugg `Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 9
User does not have permission to alter database '@dbname', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.`

Comment: `GRANT ALTER ANY DATABASE TO your_login
GO`

Comment: @Kevin You need to assign permission to your logged in user for database

Comment: still getting it, but I suppose that would be a seperate issue

Comment: I think I am going to need to use some dynamic sql for this... I have to find all db's that are online as well, and then do the backups, etc...   Thanks for the help